# Pysideの__init__の引数　Parent＝Noneについて

Tags: python, pyside

https://wiki.qt.io/PySideTutorials_Simple_Dialog_Japanese
こちらに載っているコードについてご質問があります。
下部にコード記載しております。

> def **init**(self, parent=None):
>   ____super(Form, self).**init**(parent)

という部分にて、初期化関数の引数にparent=Noneとなっておりますが
なぜparent=Noneとなるのでしょうか？
parent=QDialogとなるのかな？と思っていたのですが…

> def **init**(self, parent=QDialog):
>   ____super(Form, self).**init**(parent)

この状態ですと、エラーになりました。
そもそもクラス宣言の時点でQDialog継承しているから
Noneになる。という意味になるのでしょうか？
ご教授の程宜しくお願いいたします。

_
_
_
Code↓

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
class Form(QDialog)`

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.edit = QLineEdit("Your Name???")
        self.button = QPushButton("Push!!!")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.greetings)

    def greetings(self):
        print ("Hello", self.edit.text())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、Pythonの説明からすると、関数定義時の`parent=None`の意味は、引数`parent`のデフォルト値が`None`である、という意味です。
記載いただいたコードでは、`parent`が指定されなければ、継承元の`QDialog`のコンストラクタ`__init__()`を`__init__(None)`で実行したい、ということでしょう。

次にQt(pyside)について。
私は使ったことはないのですが、Qtにおける`parent`はクラスの継承とは全く関係がなく、QObject間の親子関係を表すものようですね。

[Qt をはじめよう！ 第7回: Qt のオブジェクトモデルを理解しよう - Qt Japanese Blog](https://blog.qt.io/jp/2010/05/05/object/)

ということは、parent引数を省略した場合 Noneを指定した場合、他のQtオブジェクトと全く関係のない新規のQtオブジェクトを作成する、ということなのだと思います。

なお、

```
def init(self, parent=QDialog):
____super(Form, self).init(parent)
```

がエラーになるのは、QDialogがあくまでクラスの名称でしかなく、継承元の`__init__()`に渡せるようなインスタンスではないからです。